# (python matplotlib ) How to change color of each lollipop in a lollipop plot (ax.stem)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am using `ax.stem` to draw lollipop plot in python. However, I found it difficult to assign different colors to each lollipop
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veCjH.png)

As you can see I have 2 categories "GWP" & "FDP". 
In my project, each category should be divided into 4 subcategories "ingredient", "Waste", "energy" and "infrastructure". Therefore, I want to assign them different colors to indicate the subcategory.

There is a solution proposed here: https://python-graph-gallery.com/181-custom-lollipop-plot/

But this only teaches you how to change color for all lollipops.

And there is another solution: https://python-graph-gallery.com/183-highlight-a-group-in-lollipop/

But this one doesn't really use `ax.stem`.

Please let me know how to assign different colors to each lollipop.

(Also, I don't know somehow why my plot is displayed upside down. Also, the y axis does not align in order, and there is one dot not connected by a line. It displays correctly in my original plot though.)

Here is my code:

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')


# my dataset
columns = np.array(['types', 'GWP100 (year)', 'FDP (year)'])


types = np.array(['Total (ingredient) per kg', 'Total (waste) per kg',
       'energy (whole process) per kg', 'Infrastructure', 'Total (Total)']).reshape(5,1)
gwp = np.array([  2.86982617e+02,   2.16824983e+02,   4.38920760e+01,
         6.02400000e-02,   5.47759916e+02]).reshape(5,1)
fdp = np.array([  1.35455867e+02,   7.02868322e+00,   1.26622560e+01,
         1.64568000e-02,   1.55163263e+02]).reshape(5,1)

original_data = np.concatenate((types, gwp, fdp), axis = 1)




# produce dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(original_data, columns = columns)

#                           types GWP100 (year)  FDP (year)
#0      Total (ingredient) per kg    286.982617  135.455867
#1           Total (waste) per kg    216.824983  7.02868322
#2  energy (whole process) per kg     43.892076   12.662256
#3                 Infrastructure       0.06024   0.0164568
#4                  Total (Total)    547.759916  155.163263


#%%  graph
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize =(8,6))

# 1st subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
gwp = data[data.columns[1]]

ax1.stem(gwp)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'kg CO$_2$-Eq', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('GWP', fontsize=10)


# 2nd subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
fdp = data[data.columns[2]]

ax2.stem(fdp)
ax2.set_ylabel(r'kg oil-Eq', fontsize = 10)
ax2.set_xlabel('FDP', fontsize=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `stem` currently consists of a couple of lines and a "line" consisting of dots on top. It has no option to colorize the lines separately within its interface.

You may replicate the stem plot to draw the lines manually with the color you like.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

columns = np.array(['types', 'GWP100 (year)', 'FDP (year)'])
types = np.array(['Total (ingredient) per kg', 'Total (waste) per kg',
       'energy (whole process) per kg', 'Infrastructure', 'Total (Total)'])
gwp = np.array([  2.86982617e+02,   2.16824983e+02,   4.38920760e+01,
         6.02400000e-02,   5.47759916e+02])
fdp = np.array([  1.35455867e+02,   7.02868322e+00,   1.26622560e+01,
         1.64568000e-02,   1.55163263e+02])

# produce dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame([types,gwp,fdp], index = columns).transpose()

colors = list("bgryk")

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

for t, y, c in zip(data["types"], data["GWP100 (year)"],colors):
    ax.plot([t,t], [0,y], color=c, marker="o", markevery=(1,2))
ax.set_ylim(0,None)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
fig.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

A more efficient solution is of course to use a `LineCollection` in combination with a scatter plot for the dots.

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

segs = np.zeros((len(data), 2, 2))
segs[:,:,0] = np.repeat(np.arange(len(data)),2).reshape(len(data),2) 
segs[:,1,1] = data["GWP100 (year)"].values

lc = LineCollection(segs, colors=colors)
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.scatter(np.arange(len(data)), data["GWP100 (year)"].values, c=colors)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data)))
ax.set_xticklabels(data["types"], rotation=90)
ax.autoscale()
ax.set_ylim(0,None)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a doubt about the loop in your 1st method.

`for t, y, c in zip(data["types"], data["GWP100 (year)"],colors):`
    `ax.plot([t]*2, [0,y], color=c, marker="o", markevery=(1,2))`

What does `[t]*2` and `[0,y]` stand for? 

It's a bit different from what I know about `ax.plot`
`ax.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,3,1,3])` would generate a line connecting (1,1), (2,3), (3,1), (4,3)

What I know is the simplest and most typical way though.
what you have done is something I never seen before

Comment: `[t]*2` simply gives you `[t,t]`. You then plot vertical lines at `[t,t]` and `[0,y]` using  `ax.plot([t,t], [0,y]` which means `ax.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])`. For a vertical line, x1 = x2

Comment: Sorry for the notation. `[t]*2` is the same as `[t,t]` for the purpose shown here. I edited the answer. Then `plot([t,t],[0,y])` is precisely what you already know about generating lines, it'll create a line from point `(t,0)` to point `(t,y)`.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer one of your main questions regarding the same coloring of the lines and markers category wise. There seems to be no direct option while calling `ax1.stem()` to specify the list of colors as per the official docs. In fact they say that the resulting plot might not be reasonable if one do so. Nevertheless, below is one trick to get things done your way.

The idea is following:

- Get the objects (`stemline`) displayed on the subplot
- Get the x-y data of the markers
- Loop over the data and change the color of each *stemline*. Plot the marker individually with the same color as *stemline*. The `colors` is an array specifying the colors of your choice.

Following is the relevant part of the code:

```
# 1st subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
gwp = data[data.columns[1]]

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'k']
_, stemlines, _ = ax1.stem(gwp)

line = ax1.get_lines()
xd = line[0].get_xdata()
yd = line[0].get_ydata()

# mec and mfc stands for markeredgecolor and markerfacecolor
for i in range(len(stemlines)):
    plt.plot([xd[i]], [yd[i]], 'o', ms=7, mfc=colors[i], mec=colors[i])
    plt.setp(stemlines[i], 'color', colors[i])

ax1.set_ylabel(r'kg CO$_2$-Eq', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('GWP', fontsize=10)


# 2nd subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
fdp = data[data.columns[2]]

_, stemlines, _ = ax2.stem(fdp)

line = ax2.get_lines()
xd = line[0].get_xdata()
yd = line[0].get_ydata()

for i in range(len(stemlines)):
    plt.plot([xd[i]], [yd[i]], 'o', ms=7, mfc=colors[i], mec=colors[i])
    plt.setp(stemlines[i], 'color', colors[i])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa! The way how you did it is the same that I wanted to try: draw the line and dot separately. I would simply use `ax.scatter` and `ax.plot` though. What you have done, such as `xd = line[0].get_xdata()` is way more clever, something that I never come up with. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can also use scatter for plotting dots without using for loops. But here the main thing was to get data from lines